# Retrieve data from firebase in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase and I an using the guide given by firebase but I am not able to create the reference with my firebase database.

```
FIRDatabaseReference * ref = [[FIRDatabase alloc]
    referenceFromURL:@"https://project-8326407164650950213.firebaseio.com"];
NSLog(@"%@",ref);
```

I am using this code to create the reference with my database but app crash.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil'

I am new in iOS and first time using firebase. Please tell me the solution as I am going  according to firebase guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no firebase expert, but when you're working with a class in Obj-C, you'll either invoke its class methods (e.g. `[FIRDatabase database]`), or you'll first allocate and initialize it (`[[FIRDatabase alloc] <an initializer>]`), and secondly use an instance method on the instance.

In your code sample above, I see an alloc without an initializer, which makes me think you're missing something.

If I look at the [iOS quick start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html), I see a call to `initWithURL`, which is one of the initializers.

Comment: can you pls explain what you did for making refrance of database in obj-c

Comment: Looks like the API has changed again:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database#properties

Now it looks like you'll need something like:
FIRApp *app = [FIRApp configure];
[FIRDatabase databaseForApp:app];

(Sorry, I can't format code in a comment -- if you want a better answer, ask a question instead of commenting on a loosely related question. ;))

Answer (score 1):

```
    Firebase *messagePath = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", MAIN_URL,MESSAGES_DIRECTORY,conversationId]];
[[messagePath queryLimitedToLast:10] observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSMutableArray *messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [messages addObject:snapshot.value];
    observingBlock(true,messages);
}];
```

- Here is the code with you can get the data and value of the node. First make url till your node.
- Still you have any problem just add comment here. now a days working on Firebase chat in swift.

Comment: Hi, the firebase class is not access now a days because it is deprecated  as mentioned in their docs.

"You're viewing the legacy docs. They are deprecated as of May 18, 2016. 

These docs are for version 2.5.1 and below of the Objective-C SDK. Go to our current docs, or see our  iOS migration guide. "

Comment: @salmancs43 I have made chat with FIRDATABASE and Authenticate user using FIRAUTH in swift latest version. I know this was older version.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve data but my code didn't go to completion block .
I just want to retrieve data from firebase only. No user authentication or saving data

Comment: Can you please see that link . I posted my question with complete code and database structure. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611505/retreiving-data-from-firebase-database

Comment: @salmancs43 I have wrote an answer on the link you provide me in comments please check that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily. If you want to fetch all info using this you can do this. Make sure you have made your db public then no auth needed

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRDatabaseReference *ref;
```

Define Property on interface then

```
 self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
     [self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

            NSLog(@"Information : %@",usersDict);
        }];
```

If you want to fetch specific portion using this you can do this

```
 [[self.ref child:@"results"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

        NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;

        NSLog(@"Info : %@",usersDict);



    }];
```

My Fetched Json From Firebase

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      },
{
"name":"test 1",
"URL" : "URL STRING"
      }
 ]
}
```