# Retrieving data from firebase database: code didn't go into the completion block or an error block

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data  from database but my code didn't go into the completion block or an error block. I didn't want any auth authentication from user and save data in database from an app. Just  want to retrieve data from database. My database structure is like that

[image]

Here is the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;
    [self referenceFromURL:@"https://project-8326407164650950213.firebaseio.com"];
}
- (FIRDatabaseReference *) referenceFromURL:(NSString *)databaseUrl{

    commentsRef = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:databaseUrl];
    return commentsRef;
}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[commentsRef child:@"Hello"]
     observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue
     withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
         NSDictionary * post = snapshot.value;

     }withCancelBlock:^(NSError * error){
         NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
     }];
}
```

Tell me what I am missing in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://project-8326407164650950213.firebaseio.com"];
    FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:strUrl];
    [ref observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *post = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@"%@",post);
    }];
```

- Here is the code with you will get your data from Firebase.
- Only problem with your code is you wrote "[commentsRef child:@"Hello"]". Use direct urlreference to fetch data.

Comment: I didn't use Error block over here.